# iPhone X layout compared to ordinary iPhone layout

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview, constraints

I have some issues following the layout. I'm not hard coding the value to an exact spot. So on the left is an iPhone 7 and on the right is the iPhone x. The purple bar is a collection view. If you look closely on the iPhone 7 I set the `imageView` (circle) `topAnchor` to the `collectionView`  `bottomAnchor`. But on the iPhone X the `bottomAnchor` isn't the bottom of the `collectionView`. It's more like the bottom of the icon. Any Idea why and how to fix?

[image: problem]

Comment: Hierarchy as follows: 1.Navigation Bar, 2. CollectionView, 3. ImageView. Is it right?

Comment: @McDonal_11 ImageView is behind collectionView so it's more like 1 3 2

Comment: possible, try change hierarchy. I have checked here. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pin it to the top by something like 2 3 pt it should work but as i see your whole ui doesnt have proper constraints so my suggestion is clear all  constraints and start adding from top to buttom

Comment: it's 8pt from the top though